# extract interface from * import variable

Tags: node.js, typescript

if I have

```
// file 1
interface IBarf {d: String}
export {
  a: "foo",  
  IBarf
}

// file 2
import * as foos from './file1'
const {IBarf} = foos // ERROR , can't apply interface to a const
```

what's the way to get the interface from an import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question is

```
type IBarf = foos.IBarf
```

Answer (score 0):

> what's the way to get the interface from an import?

That is not the issue. Issue is *you cannot use an interface as a variable*. [It must only be used as a Type](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/project/declarationspaces.html).